# Right way or method Do While If Condition set inside loop?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I can't figure out the right way to do that:

I'm calling external API for products and I get a response I want to add those products to my database and if the response contains a next_page url loop it again until there is no next_page left

Here is what I came up with:

```
var products = api.ProductsActive('GET', {includes: 'Images', limit: 1}); 

requestProducts = function(){ 
  products.results.forEach(function(product){ 
    var sameproduct = apiProducts.findOne({listing_id: product.listing_id}); 
    if (sameproduct) { 
      console.log('found sameproduct');
      return;
    }
    //Add userId to current product so we can assosicate products belong to "X" user
    var productExtend = _.extend(product, {userId: Meteor.userId()}); 
    apiProducts.insert(productExtend);
  });

  //If there is next page get the next page number and get products
  var nextPage = products.pagination.next_page;
  if (nextPage !== null) {
    products = api.ProductsActive('GET', {includes: 'Images', page: nextPage, limit: 1});
    console.log(products);
  }
};

//loop at least once, and then if more pages found
do {
      requestProducts();
   }
while (products.pagination.next_page !== null);
```

Which doesn't seems to work right I'm not sure if this is the right method for such function I really help your input! Please help me figure out the right way for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind javascript is asynchronous, so you need to handle your loop with callbacks instead of `do`. The reason for this is requestProducts likely uses a callback and the javascript interpreter doesn't "wait" for `requestProducts()` to finish running before it runs the next line of code.

You haven't provided any details of how the api works so I have to generalise.

If `requestProducts()` takes a parameter as a callback (which it should), use that to re-run itself:

```
 var callback = function(err, result) {
     if(products.pagination.next_page !== null) requestProducts(callback);
 };

 requestProducts(callback);
```

You would have to check the your api's documentation to check how the callback is defined but it would be something like the above where `err` is returned if there is a problem.

How this works is, when requestProducts is called the callback fires and if its not the last page to repeat itself until `..next_page == null`

Comment: Yes you're correct it's with callbacks it's meteor and I have the options to choose with callback or not, I have created that API prototype so I will definitely will figure out something now, Thanks a lot for letting me know that I should use callback to repeat the action I wasn't really sure how to approach this and this makes sense, I will research and read & read more about callbacks to make it clear and code something :)

Comment: Actually my server side code is synchronized, but the call from the client is asynchronized so I came up with this code which seems to work can you comment on it is it fine or is this a hack and I completly wrong on everything I just read on callbacks :)? http://pastebin.com/bahTa50G

Comment: @zumbamusic it would be fine so long as `api.ProductsActive` allows synchronous results. I'm not sure which API this is, but if its designed for Meteor using a fiber then you're fine. If its an ordinary nodejs api you could make it synchronous using `Meteor.wrapAsync` (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync). You need to be careful you use a Fiber for each one so that you can use Meteor code in each with their own scoped environment.

Comment: it's my own API and it's synchronous results. I did `var results = meteor.call...` so awesome this is working now great now going to post another interesting question about MongoDB there is no joins in the core :(

Comment: oh ok. If you've used Meteor.call and the HTTP package somehow it'll all be fiberized and no problem